# Why is this getting random user IDs and not the current user?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Some developers in my company are having a problem with developing an in-house system.  In the code snippet below, winID should be assigned the current system's user's ID.  Instead, it's being assigned someone else's ID, apparently at random.  Any suggestions?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Theme = "MasterTheme1";
        if (Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            using (((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Impersonate())
            {
                WindowsIdentity winID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                Session["UserName"] = winID.Name;
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("MainDB_Login.aspx");
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //Snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly cacheing in place (browser, or on server)?